# Replace rows in each groups, by the first row value. Pandas Groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
                   'B' : ['1', '2','2', '4', '1']})
```

Below is how I want it to look,

[image]

And here is how I have tried and failed.

```
groups = df.groupby([A])
groups.apply(lambda g: g[g[B] == g[B].first()]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')
```

or, if data already sorted by `A` as showned:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df['A'].duplicated()).ffill()
```

Output:

```
     A  B
0  foo  1
1  foo  1
2  bar  2
3  bar  2
4  bar  2
```

Comment: I was curious on the performance of this. 
Having a dataset of 171 455 rows with 55 006 distinct groups, using %%timit.
group by method: 77 ms ± 3.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
ffill method: 16.4 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
ffill is more prone to error if the sorting of your df is changed somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use `drop_duplicates` + `repeat`

```
s=df.drop_duplicates('A')
s=s.reindex(s.index.repeat(df.A.value_counts()))
Out[555]: 
     A  B
0  foo  1
0  foo  1
0  foo  1
2  bar  2
2  bar  2
```